# FileReader can't read file

Tags: java

I got an error "Unhandled Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException, though I'm sure about the file path, need some help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    int total =0;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Numbers.txt"));
}
```

Comment: By "I got an error" do you mean it's not compiling, or does it happen when you run your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code lacks of Exception handling. You are sure about the file presence, but the program is not, at *compilation* time. Just declare it on main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

}
```

Or use a try-catch block:

```
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Numbers.txt"));
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a compile-time error. FileNotFoundException is a checked exception which means that you have to state what Java should do if it is encountered.
There may be a case where the file may not be present so Java asking you to handle that scenario either by try/catch block or throws keyword

To make your code work jus add as below :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
```

Comment: Request you to please copy the above code and try to compile it ? How can you compile the code without declaring checked exception ? It will be a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

could you please try with

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Numbers.txt"));
```